# $m->comp is returning infinite recursive call error

Tags: html, perl, mason

I am having trouble using HTML::Mason's `$m->comp` to redirect from one view to another.

There is a file say `file1.mi` which has embedded HTML code in this `file1.mi` I am using `$m->comp` to redirect to `file2.mi`.

But in the webpage whenever `file1.mi` is loaded it prints the footer multiple times and in the logs i am getting the errors

> Nested page framework application dispatch detected, this usage is not
>   fully supported and may result in unexpected behavior

and

> Error: APPLICATION CONTEXT ERROR (RENDER): 32 levels deep in component
>   stack (infinite recursive call?)

.  Here is the script which i am using for redirecting from `file1.mi`

```
return $m->comp('/page-framework/dispatch.mi', applicationPath =>'/gp/tradein/omc', viewID => 'file2.mi', %ARGS);
```

I am using this script in `file1.mi` before it renders the webpage -- i.e. before any HTML scripts are executed.

I am kinda new to Mason, if you have queries regarding this please go ahead.

Comment: little correction let say viewID of file2.mi is "file2".

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more of your code in order to give you a suitable answer.  In particular, the context of the `return` above and some portion of `dispatch.mi` seem like they would help here.

Comment: You probably don't want to be posting proprietary code on here. BTW, It's pretty easy for people to figure out the team that owns /gp/tradein/omc/*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your file1.mi gets loaded and rendered, then file2.mi gets executed and it in infinite loop.

Please, show us more code, it is not possible to debug with that small details.

What do you in the web server logs? Please, paste some example from loglines too.

Regards,

Comment: I think file2.mi is not ever executed because i have put up a FLLogError at the begining of file2.mi but it is not executing.
Moreover file1.mi is not rendering. It is just showing header of the template multiple time. There is not much in log file except those session details.

Answer (score 0):

It should be your dispatcher `dispatch.mi` that is calling file1 or file2.  Deciding that you want to go elsewhere after the request has already been dispatched seems like the logic is in the wrong place.